# Is an index method needed here? (python)

Tags: python, list

am trying to build a word guessing game. The function I'm trying to build should be able to display correctly guessed and repeating letters alongside blanks for not-yet-guessed letters. I got an index out of range error. Should I write an index method for all guesses and then reformat it back to string?

```
import random

Dictionary = {"fruits": "papaya", "buildings": "apartment", "mammal": "horse"}

def choose_word():
    hint, chosen_word = random.choice(list(Dictionary.items()))
    print("Hint: " + hint)
    for letter in chosen_word:
        blank = []
        blank.append("_")
        print("".join(blank), end="")
    player_guess = input("\nPlease guess a letter between A-Z\n")
    letter = 0
    if player_guess in chosen_word:
        while chosen_word.find(player_guess, letter) != -1:
            letter = chosen_word.find(player_guess, letter)
            blank[letter] = player_guess
            letter += 1
    print("".join(blank))


choose_word()
```

Comment: @Tim Roberts, I repost the comment as question here. Do have a look, thanks!

Comment: `random.choice` returns a number, how do you unpack it? When I try to reproduce your example I get a `TypeError` Please see [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @RMPR I updated the question with the dictionary for the random function. My bad that I forgot about it initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `blank` list only has one element, because you are re-initializing the value for each iteration of this loop:

```
for letter in chosen_word:
    blank = []
    blank.append("_")
    print("".join(blank), end="")
```

You need to move the initialization statement out of the loop:

```
blank = []

for letter in chosen_word:
    blank.append("_")

print("".join(blank))
```

(I also moved the print statement to the end so the code prints the list of blanks just once, as discussed in the comments.)

Comment: the problem is, after I moved the assignment `blank` outside the loop, what gets printed out is every new iteration + previous iteration. For example if the word is 'horse', what gets printed out is "_" * 15 times.

Comment: @Kentta Yes, that's because you're printing the entire list for each iteration of the loop. So the first time it will print `_`, the second time it will print `__`, and so on.  If you want to print the whole list of blanks just one time, you can move the `print` statement after the loop.

Comment: @Kentta I'm glad to hear it.  If this answered your question you can click the "check mark" next to this answer to mark it as the solution.